# CKeditor + java upload image

Tags: javascript, java, ckeditor4.x

I've seen many examples of "*how to upload an image using CKeditor*" and almost all of the examples I could comprehend were all done in **PHP**. I am building a project in ***java*** and all the examples don't quite relate to my project.

I would like to know if there are examples that are more **java** or **spring-mvc** related.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here's what I tried to do but I kept getting the same error when I clicked the send to server button.

**Html file**

```
<div class="editor">
  <div><label for="nome-do-produto-3" class="form-field-label">Informações gerais</label>
  <textarea placeholder="Rich text" maxlength="5000" id="info-field" name="info-field" class="form-text-field _90 w-input">
   </textarea></div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
     CKEDITOR.replace( 'info-field', {
      height: 100,
      filebrowserUploadUrl: "/image/upload"
     });
    </script>
```

**Controller.java**

```
@PostMapping("/image/upload")
    @SneakyThrows
    public String upload(@RequestPart MultipartFile upload, HttpServletRequest request) throws IllegalStateException, IOException{
    String path = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
    File files = new File(path + "upload");
    files.mkdir();
    upload.transferTo(new File(files.getPath()+File.separator+upload.getOriginalFilename()));
    System.out.println(upload.getOriginalFilename());
    return                                                           request.getScheme()+"://"+request.getServerName()+":"+request.getServerPort()+"/upload/"+upload.getOriginalFilename();
}
```

**Image upload view**

[image: ![Right after I clicked the send-to-server button]

Right after I clicked the send-to-server button

[image]

I want it to show uploaded **image url** on the **image info tab**.

**The error on console**

`org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [http://localhost:8080/upload/image-1.jpg], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers`

Comment: First get your upload endpoint working without CKEditor, either use your favorite POST tool or make a vanilla form to upload an image. Once you've verified that your endpoint works then connect CKEditor to it.

Answer (score 0):

filebrowserUploadUrl: "/image/upload" replace with url filebrowserUploadUrl: "image/upload" hopefull it will work

Comment: Hello, your answer might be more helpful to other users if you could explain a little bit about how it works :)